# Error when scraping with Beautiful Soup and Selenium together

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm a beginner in Python and web scraping in general. In this code I'm using both Bs4 and Selenium. I'm using Selenium to make clicking on the 'show more' button automatic,so that I can scrape all of the results, not just the ones found on the first page of results shown. 
I'm trying to scrape the following website: https://boards.euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/search?query=improve

However, when combining Bs4 and Selenium together, 3 fields that I'm scraping (username, server and topic) now give me the following two errors.

1)  I get a AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' for both server and username

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "failoriginale.py", line 153, in <module>
    main()
  File "failoriginale.py", line 132, in main
    song_data = get_songs(index_page) # Get songs with metadata
  File "failoriginale.py", line 81, in get_songs
    username = row.find(class_='username').text.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

2)I get this error with topic

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "failoriginale.py", line 153, in <module>
    main()
  File "failoriginale.py", line 132, in main
    song_data = get_songs(index_page) # Get songs with metadata
  File "failoriginale.py", line 86, in get_songs
    topic = row.find('div', {'class':'discussion-footer byline opaque'}).find_all('a')[1].text.strip()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

However, before combining bs4 with Selenium, these 3 fields worked just like the others, so I think that the problem is elsewhere. I don't get it what's the problem in the main function with song_data?  I have already looked up other questions on stackoverflow but I could not solve the problem. I'm new to scraping and bs4, selenium libraries so sorry if I'm asking a silly question.

Here's  the code:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='./geckodriver')
browser.get('https://boards.euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/search?query=improve&content_type=discussion')
html = browser.page_source #page_source is where selenium stores the html source

def get_songs(url):

    html = browser.page_source
    index_page = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml') # Parse the page

    items = index_page.find(id='search-results') # Get the list on from the webpage
    if not items: # If the webpage does not contain the list, we should exit
        print('Something went wrong!', file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit()
    data = list()
 # button show more, if the page has the show more button, it will click on that x5secs
    if index_page.find('a', {"class": "box show-more",}):
        button = browser.find_element_by_class_name('box.show-more')
        timeout = time.time() + 5
        while True:
            button.click()
            time.sleep(5.25)
            if time.time() > timeout:
                break

html = browser.page_source
    index_page = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
    items = index_page.find(id='search-results')

    for row in items.find_all(class_='discussion-list-item'):

        username = row.find(class_='username').text.strip()
        question = row.find(class_='title-span').text.strip()
        sentence = row.find('span')['title']
        serverzone = row.find(class_='realm').text.strip()
        #print(serverzone)
        topic = row.find('div', {'class':'discussion-footer byline opaque'}).find_all('a')[1].text.strip()
        #print(topic)
        date=row.find(class_='timeago').get('title')
        #print(date)
        views = row.find(class_='view-counts byline').find('span', {'class' : 'number opaque'}).get('data-short-number')
        comments = row.find(class_='num-comments byline').find('span', {'class' : 'number opaque'}).get('data-short-number')

        # Store the data in a dictionary, and add that to our list
        data.append({
                     'username': username,
                     'topic':topic,
                     'question':question,
                     'sentence':sentence,
                     'server':serverzone,
                     'date':date,
                     'number_of_comments':comments,
                     'number_of_views':views
                    })
    return data
def get_song_info(url):
    browser.get(url)
    html2 = browser.page_source
    song_page = BeautifulSoup(html2, features="lxml")
    interesting_html= song_page.find('div', {'class' : 'list'})
    if not interesting_html: # Check if an article tag was found, not all pages have one
        print('No information availible for song at {}'.format(url), file=sys.stderr)
        return {}
    answer = interesting_html.find('span', {'class' : 'high-quality markdown'}).find('p').text.strip() #.find('span', {"class": "high-quality markdown",}).find('p')
    return {'answer': answer} # Return the data of interest



def main():
    index_page = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
    song_data = get_songs(index_page) # Get songs with metadata
     #for each row in the improve page enter the link and extract the data  
    for row in song_data:
        print('Scraping info on {}.'.format(row['link'])) # Might be useful for debugging
        url = row['link'] #defines that the url is the column link in the csv file 
        song_info = get_song_info(url) # Get lyrics and credits for this song, if available
        for key, value in song_info.items():
            row[key] = value # Add the new data to our dictionary
    with open('results.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f: # Open a csv file for writing
        fieldnames=['link','username','topic','question','sentence','server','date','number_of_comments','number_of_views','answer'] # These are the values we want to store
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to use requests to retrieve the total results count and number of results per batch and loop clicking the button with a wait condition until all results present. Then grab them in one go so to speak. Outline below which can be re-written as required. You could always use an `n` end point to stop clicking after `n` pages and increment `n` within loop. You might additionally add 
`WebDriverWait(d,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.inline-profile .username')))` initially at the end before collecting the other items to allow time after last click.

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

data = requests.get('https://boards.euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/search?query=improve&json_wrap=1').json()
total = data['searchResultsCount']
batch = data['resultsCount']

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://boards.euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/search?query=improve')

counter = batch
while counter < total:
    WebDriverWait(d, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.show-more-label'))).click()
    counter +=batch
    #print(counter)

userNames = [item.text for item in d.find_elements_by_css_selector('.inline-profile .username')]
topics = [item.text for item in d.find_elements_by_css_selector('.inline-profile + a')]
servers = [item.text for item in d.find_elements_by_css_selector('.inline-profile .realm')]
results = list(zip(userNames, topics, servers))
```

Interestingly, it does seem to stop updating before the given end count despite being able to click the button. This happens also when manually clicking.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply but I have been trying multiple times without success, I have tried to integrate the code with your suggestion. Even if the timer works fine  I keep getting several errors. The last one i'm getting is the following:  for row in song_data:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable  
Since I'm new to this I don't know if it is because I'm putting the code in the wrong place. I have another question: what do you mean by 'Then grab them in one go'.  Thanks

Comment: pastebin.com your code. Grab in one go - I click until all results are present so I grab all results in one go rather than grab a batch, click, grab another batch etc.